# YCSB POM.xml contents for Hbase 0.90.6-cdh3u6

Tags: maven, hbase, cloudera, ycsb

What should be the contents of POM.xml for HBase version 0.90.6-cdh3u6 (cloudera version)?

I tried updating my POM.xml according to [this](http://cloudfront.blogspot.in/2013/02/how-to-benchmark-hbase-using-ycsb.html#.VUeB5Pmqqkp) but am getting errors when am building YCSB using maven .

Let me know the POM.xml contents for the cloudera hbase verion 0.90.6-cdh3u6.
Thanks.

Comment: What is the error your getting?

Comment: BTW: Are you really using Maven 2?

Comment: am using maven 3.3.3.